# installing gevent in windows

Tags: python, pip, gevent

I m new to python.I installed python 3.4 and tried to run the commamd
"pip install gevent" but it shows the error "TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() >= str()".How to resolve this.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's because `gevent` [only supports Python 2.5 and greater](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gevent#downloads):

```
Operating System :: MacOS :: MacOS X
Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows
Operating System :: POSIX
Programming Language :: Python :: 2.5
Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6
Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7
```

Solution: **you have to install the Python 2.x version for Windows so that you can use `gevent` as desired.**

Comment: thanks @jrd1...but pip is installed default in python 3.4...so i used it...but in python 2.x versions i tried to install pip but i can't...so help me ..

Comment: @Reddevil: do you have Python 2.x installed? If so, then download pip and install it like you would any other module (using the `setuptools` module): `python setup.py install`.

Comment: @Reddevil: follow this tutorial for more: http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html

Once done, you can then use that pip to install `gevent`

Comment: thanks @jrd1 I m just downloading python 2.7 after if i get any error..i get back to u...

Comment: @Reddevil: Cool. If my post was useful to you, please consider it for acceptance. :)

Comment: ...u r assist s valuable to me..once i finished installing i do yhat

Comment: Good answer. You included a link, and its authentic. Certainly more detailed than mine :)

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: Thank you. However, I'm of the opinion that both of our answers are good and authentic. ;) Thanks for the comment and show of support! :)

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is because `gevent` does not support python 3 yet. This is why you're getting the error right now.

Comment: thank u for ur reply @Brianiac...but i want to install gevent for my project...wat can I do..

Comment: What you can do is install python 2.7.*, the latest version of python 2, and then install `gevent`. If you're using mac/linux, you might want to use `pyenv`, which allows you to easily manage your python environments. Otherwise, you might want to simply install python 2 from the setup files from the python.org website. Then you'd need to change your PATH variable.

Comment: @LieRyan `pyenv` does not work on windows I'm afraid.

Comment: Ah, I mean both [Ian Bicking's virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) and the [standard library venv](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/venv.html), the latter uses pyenv as the default for command line script name. I didn't know about [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) until just now. What's the advantage of pyenv over the other more popular env solutions?

Comment: @LieRyan virtualenv is there for managing different virtual environments. Pyenv is more like node version manager, or nvm for short. In essence if you want to work with different types of python, say cpython 2, cpyhon 3, pypy, stackless, jython, and you wantto switch between them easily, then pyenv is for you.

Comment: @LieRyan If you'd like we can talk more about it in chat.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 64 bit using Python 2.7:
Install greenlet (pip install greenlet)
Then install Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0  (as of 2015-01-20) at http://aka.ms/vcpython27
Then you can install gevent through pip (pip install gevent)

If you are not sure how to install on windows using pip it is a download also.  I was using pip-Win 1.7